# Joomla! 2.5 language file - translate description

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I create a new plugin for joomla 2.5, and in xml i use:

```
<description>PLG_VAR_DESC</description>
```

But when install, he dont show the the translation but the var on file.

```
<languages folder="">
  <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.plg_system_name.ini</language>
  <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.plg_system_name.sys.ini</language>
</languages>
<files>
   <folder>images</folder>
   <filename>index.html</filename>
   <filename>parameters.xml</filename>
   <filename plugin="plg_name">plg_name.php</filename>
</files>
```

I try everything but i cant put this work..

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Under the administrator panel in Joomla! you can find under Site - Global configuration - System:

[image: Joomla! Debug language]

This will allow you to see the Joomla! Debug console:

[image: Joomla! debug console]

There you can see if the language file your are using is loaded. If it's not loaded, than your manifest file is not consistent.

I think that the problem could be solved with:

`<languages folder="admin">`

instead of

`<languages folder="">`

Also for your reference, the Joomla! documentation on ["Specification of language files"](http://docs.joomla.org/1.6:_Specification_of_language_files) may be a good read.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.. is the name of language file. Thank's for helping me